# Unable to configure wifi on debian 6

Tags: linux, networking, debian, wireless-networking

I have installed Debian on my Toshiba satellite laptop. I'm having Net-gear WiFi router with me. Normally in Cent OS I can see after booting there will be gnome network manager. But there is no gnome network manager in Debian after booted. Also there is no settings for the network in the system menu.

When I tried to start from terminal :

root@debian:~ifup wlan0

unkown interface wlan0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi), or installing Network Manager for GNOME `aptitude install network-manager`, maybe you need tools for wireless `aptitude install wireless-tools`. Your approach is too abstract without dumping more data

Comment: I thought these basic things will be installed by default. I checked the Debian website just now. Since without internet couldn't check it from my  home. Will it install these from local repos? Since we can't connect to online repos currently.

Comment: It didn't worked. When I tired there is no such thing in the repos. I removed it and installed GNU Linux finally. One thing I noted that Debian consumes less memory as compared other distros. But without internet it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

There are not enough data. Most probably you wifi card is not supported by default setup (this is very often problem for laptops) and you should install some third-party modules. May be you also need to install network-manager by hand.

Answer (score 0):

That means you have no wireless interface called wlan0. This might be due to:

1) Your IF is called differently. The command

```
  iwconfig
```

will show the wireless capabilities of your IFs. If the output for one or more of the IFs is **not**

```
 no wireless extensions.
```

*that's* your wireless card.

2) Your wifi is not enabled. This is the case if the output of

```
iw list
```

is empty. In this case, it means your wifi is not recognized. This may happen for two reasons: one, Linux does not have a suitable driver *at all* for your card, or the driver does exist, but it requires some work. The first case is of course hopeless, so let us concentrate on the second one.

In order to identify your card, if it is *not* a USB adapter, you will have to issue this command:

```
lspci -nn | grep -i Net
```

This will output a few lines like these,

```
 00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
 04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
```

Of this, the first one is my Ethernet connection, the second one is my wifi card. The important piece is the code 8086:088E, which is called the Vendor+Product code of your chipset.

If you have an external USB wifi adapter, you can obtain the same code by means of the command

```
 lsusb
```

(bonus question: why can't you use lspci? ;-)

With this info in hand, you can search for your card in the search bar of [the WikiDevi Web site](http://wikidevi.com/wiki/Main_Page), which will locate the relevant information for your card for various operating systems, among which there is surely Linux. In particular, it will tell you what the appropriate driver for your card is. The information might be missing, in which case there is no driver for Linux.

Let us now suppose your driver is iwlwifi (it is appropriate to me card), and I would like to know whether my system is using this driver. I can do this by means of the command

```
 lsmod | grep iwlwifi
```

which will select info about iwlwifi from the list of all loaded modules. If you find that your driver is loaded, but wifi is not working, it is most likely because it is missing *firmware*. This is highly likely, at this stage, because firmware is proprietary software, and many distros, including Debian, do not install it automatically out of the desire to comply to the fullest with the principles of FOSS (Free Open Source Software). But don't lose heart, a simple Google search for "debian name_of_your_driver firmware" will uncover all the info you need. Alternatively, you can go the [Linux Wireless Web site](http://wireless.kernel.org/), write the name of your driver in the search box, and you will get all the info you need on it and its firmware.

If your wifi still does not work, we need to check whether by any chance you are using an old driver. You do this by issuing the command (for my card, change the command to suit your card):

```
 modinfo name_of_driver | grep 8086 | grep 088E
```

(careful, hexadecimal figures are represented by *CAPITAL* letters). If this returns nothing, you do indeed have an old version of the driver, and you will have to install the new one through the Linux Backports. These are a series of modules implementing new functionalities, or supporting new pieces of hardware, which are standard with new versions of the Linux kernel, but are absent in older versions. The backports port these new drivers to oler versions of the kernel, to allow them to take advantage of all that's new since your kernel release. You can find info on how to install backports [on this very site](https://superuser.com/questions/649700/how-can-i-patch-compile-and-install-a-linux-driver), except that the commands

```
 su -  
 yum install make automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel kernel-headers
```

should be replaced by

```
 sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

and the name of your driver should replace that in the example referenced above.

3) This last step (the search in the [Linux Wireless Web site](http://wireless.kernel.org/)) is necessary as a last resort if all I have said so far fails. It could be that your driver is prevented from loading by a conflict with another driver, so that it is *blacklisted*. If this is the case, the Linux Wireless Web page will tell you this is so, what the conflict is, and how to solve it. In general, the conflict is between FOSS drivers and proprietary drivers. By and large, FOSS drivers are far superior, for a simple reason: whenever the proprietary driver works properly, there is no need to write a new driver. FOSS drivers are written by volunteers, often quite competent people, who dedicate to this task their free time. No one wishes to waste time unless there is some impelling need to do so.